# Using DependencyResolver.GetService() inside UserManager.CreateAsync

Tags: asp.net, inversion-of-control, asp.net-identity, structuremap, dependency-resolver

I'm struggling with a problem when using `DependencyResolver.GetService()` inside a method called from `UserManager.CreateAsync()` in `AspNet.Identity`.

I've added a UserProfile class to the AspNetUser according to 
[this article](http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customizing-users-profile-to-add-new.html).

All works fine but when creating a new user it tries to create my UserProfile entity as well and inside this I have an attribute `[CheckIfExists]` checks if the UserProfile already exists. In this method, let's call it `CheckIfExists()`, I use `DependencyResolver.GetService()` to resolve my interface `ICheckIfExists` to the "concreate" class `CheckIfExists`. This fails since the current thread is not part of the HttpContext (since it's running in CreateAsync():s thread).

Has anyone encountered this problem? Is there a solution for it? I'm using StructureMap for IoC.

Comment: This is orthogonal to your question but if you're using your IoC container as a service locator you're not really doing IoC.